# Attach output to a state in Finite State Machine in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, state-machines

In my digital electronics class we are currently dealing with Finite-State-Machines and VHDL.

I have written a VHDL-code for finite state machine and I've run into trouble. I want to attach the output to my state, but I don't know how to do it.

For example, I have a state \$S_0\$ where the outputs are \$z_0 =0\$, \$z_1=0\$, \$z_3=0\$.

How do I "attach" that output to \$S_0\$ in terms of VHDL-coding?

Something like: \$S_0: z_0 <=0; z_1<=0; z_2<=0;\$

just gives me: "\$S_0\$ is already defined in this region".

**Here is my VHDL-code. I have no idea if what I've written make sense, but hopefully, you can help me?**

```
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity Thunderbird is
    port(   B        :  in  std_logic;
            L         :    in    std_logic;
            R         :    in    std_logic;
            H         :    in    std_logic;
            Reset     :    in    std_logic;
            Clock     :    in    std_logic;
            L0,L1,L2 :    out    std_logic;
            R0,R1,R2 :    out    std_logic);
end Thunderbird;

architecture Behavioral of Thunderbird is

type state_type is (s00, sH, sB, sR1, sRB1, sR2, sRB2, sR3, sL1, sLB1, sL2, sLB2, sL3, sTB, sRB0, sLB0);
signal current_state, next_state: state_type;
begin

process(all)
begin
    if rising_edge(Clock) then
        if Reset = '1'
            then current_state <= s00;
            else
            current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end if;


    case current_state is
    when s00 => 
         if H ='1' then next_state <= sH;
           elsif 
            H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sB;
           elsif 
              H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL1;
            elsif 
              H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB1;
            elsif
             H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '0'  then next_state <= sR1; 
            elsif
             H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '1'  then next_state <= sRB1;
        end if;

    when sH => 
        next_state <= s00;

    when sB =>
        if H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= s00;
        elsif
           H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
        elsif
        H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '1' then next_state <=sRB1;
        elsif
        H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <=sLB1;
        elsif
        H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <=sL1;
        elsif
        H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR1;
       end if;

    when sR1 =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <=sR2;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sRB2;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
       end if;

    when sR2 =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR3;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sTB;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
       end if;

    when sR3 =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= s00;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sRB0;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
        end if;

    when sRB1 =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR2;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sRB2;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
        end if;

   when sRB2 =>
    if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR3;
    elsif 
    H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sTB;
    elsif
    H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
       end if;

   when sL1 =>
   if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <=sL2;
   elsif
   H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB2;
   elsif
   H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
       end if;

   when sL2 =>
   if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL3;
   elsif
   H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sTB;
   elsif
   H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
   end if;

    when sL3 =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= s00;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB0;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
       end if;

    when sRB0 =>
      if H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
      elsif 
      H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sB;
      elsif 
      H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL1;
      elsif 
      H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB1;
      elsif
      H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR1; 
      elsif
      H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '1' then next_state <= sRB1;
      end if;

     when sLB0 =>
     if H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
     elsif 
     H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sB;
     elsif 
     H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL1;
     elsif 
     H = '0' and L = '1' and R = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB1;
     elsif
     H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1' and B = '0' then next_state <= sR1; 
     elsif
     H = '0' and L = '0' and R = '1'and B = '1' then next_state <= sRB1;
     end if;  

      when sLB1 =>
         if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL2;
           elsif
           H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sLB2;
           elsif
           H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
           end if;

      when sLB2 =>
       if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= sL3;
       elsif 
       H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sTB;
       elsif
       H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
          end if;

     when sTB =>
        if H = '0' and B = '0' then next_state <= s00;
        elsif
        H = '0' and B = '1' then next_state <= sB;
        elsif
        H = '1' then next_state <= sH;
        end if;

        end case;
end process;


end Behavioral;
```

Comment: Can you share more of your code, so that we can see how you defined `S0` and what structure you used for your FSM?

Comment: I have added some additional information.

Comment: OK, sorry I am a Verilog guy so can't give you VHDL syntax. But basically for each output you will write a decoder that has the state variable as inputs and outputs the correct value depending on the state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For writing concurrent code (outside of a clocked process), try this:

```
z0 <= '0' when (current_state = s00) else
      '1' when (current_state = sh) else
      '0'; --when others

z1 <= '0' when (current_state = s00) else
      '0' when (current_state = sh) else
      '1'; --when others
```

make sure that the last selection doesn't have a "when (...)" or else you will produce inferred latches (bad). Another way to do this would be to assign z0,z1, etc directly at the same location you are assigning next_state to current state:

```
if (next_state = s00) then
   z0 <= '0';
   z1 <= '0';
elsif (next_state = sh) then
   z0 <= '1';
   z1 <= '0';
else
   z0 <= '0';
   z1 <= '1';
end if;
```

Either make a signal named "z0" and "z1" in your architecture declaration section (and then drive the appropriate output), or add "z0" and "z1" as an output port to your module.